# ZendFramework 2 tutorials and ide

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Whats the best id to use with ZendFramework 2 ? and whats the easiest source to learn ZendFramework?

I am new to zend framework.. and I would rather have some book or at least some easy to understand documentation when it comes to zend framework2?

Any of you use Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Framework 2 has been released only a few days ago, so there are not all too much resources available. As far as I am concerned, no book that covers 2.0 has been published yet. However, it should be only a matter of weeks until there will be books available (e.g. Rob Allen already [announced](http://akrabat.com/zfia/zend-framework-2-in-action/) a sequel of his book "Zend Framework in Action" which covers version 2). Don't use Books that cover 1.0, because the changes between ZF1 and ZF2 are too big.

For the moment, a good starting point for ZF2 would be the [Skeleton Application](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app) that shows the basic structure and of course the [Programmer’s Reference Guide of Zend Framework 2](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, no intellisense i guess :(

Comment: You're welcome. No, as far as I am concerned not. Zend Studio offers [Zend Framework integration](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/features#ZFI), but very likely it does also not cover ZF2 yet.

Comment: fyi: Rob Allen has recently stated at a Webinar, that no ZF2iA will be published for now.
As far as an IDE is concerned. Every IDE has intellisense as long as its PHP5 compatible. IDEs i know of are StormPHP, PHPEdit as well as Zend Studio. The upcoming ZDudio Version will have a deeper ZF2 support integrated as well.